# WinForms - How do I overlay an image of a certain size with transparency over another image of a different size?

Tags: c#, image, winforms

I'm new to C# and developing a program that calculates how large an astronomical object will appear through different telescopes and eyepieces. My code does everything I need and I have a value for the Field of View (FOV) and the size of the object. I have images of the objects and a PNG of a black circle. The black circle should stay the same size, and the object should change size depending on the field of view. I need to have the black circle over the image of the object, and be able to change the size of the object independently of the circle.

I have tried having two picture boxes with the black circle on top, but Windows Forms doesn't appear to support transparency in PNGs, so the object image does not show. The only way I have found the transparency to work is by using one picturebox with the object as the background and the black circle as the image, or using image as a parent but then I cannot seem to be able to change the size of the object independently.

```
//setting the image box as a parent of the black circle box
            astroObjectBox.Controls.Add(fovBox);
            fovBox.Location = new Point(0, 0);
            fovBox.BackColor = Color.Transparent;


private void formResultFOV_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Image astroObject = Image.FromFile(objPath);
            int imgWidth = Convert.ToInt32(mainFOV * astroObject.Width); 
            int imgHeight = Convert.ToInt32(mainFOV * astroObject.Height);
            astroObjectBox.Image = astroObject;
            astroObjectBox.Width = imgWidth;
            astroObjectBox.Height = imgHeight;
            fovBox.Image = Image.FromFile("..\\..\\..\\assets\\FOVoutline.png");
        }
```

Here's the black circle

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lmREA.png

And here's the result when using the image as a parent, it resizes the black circle to the height of the object

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kOY9y.png

Is there a way of doing this such that either the pictureboxes will be transparent or that I can size the images independently? I have also tried almost every combination of the properties (SizeMode, Anchor, Dock).

Comment: Then define size of the Image of the object, paint the transparent PNG over it and paint the combined bimap on a PictureBox/Panel/Label/Form etc. Or assign the combined Bitmap to a control that supports Bitmaps as Image of BackgroundImage.

Comment: @Jimi Thank you, how do I paint the transparent PNG and then paint the combined bitmap? I'm new to C# so not sure on this.

Comment: Define a new Bitmap, with a scale calculated using the ratio `[DisplaySize] /  [OriginalImageMaxDimension]`. Use [Graphics.FromImage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.fromimage) to create a graphics object that will paint on the new Bitmap, then [Graphics.DrawImage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.drawimage) to draw the original Image on the new Bitmap, using the original Image size as reference (it will scale automatically). Then draw the second image over it with the same method.

Comment: If the size ratio of the transparent PNG doesn't match the original Bitmap size, you might need to *manually* fill the gaps using the same color. You can also use the result of the intersection of two Regions (a rectangular region and an elliptical region) to generate the same transparent circle. When this nw Bitmap is drawn, you can draw it on a Control or assign it to a Control's property of type Image.

Comment: @Jimi Thank you very much. I've tried this but don't even know where to begin, might you be able to link me to a tutorial that would do something similar? (I'm very new to c# and windows forms)

Comment: You really need to give it a shot. If you cannot get it to work, post the code that's not working. See the Docs I linked. You can find some examples there.

Comment: @Jimi - Here's what I tried ````Bitmap final = new Bitmap(imgWidth, imgHeight);
            Graphics newGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(final);
            newGraphics.DrawImage(astroObject);
            newGraphics.DrawImage(fovOutline);
            pictureBox.Image = final;```` It says no overload for method DrawImage takes 1 arguments?

Comment: I've linked the Docs about `Graphics.DrawImage()` for your convenience. To get started, see the examples you find there.

Comment: @Jimi each of the examples are within their own void with the PaintEventArgs? Do I need this as well, how do I call them? I can't seem to be able to find anywhere in the Graphics.DrawImage documentation that draws an image to a bitmap?

Comment: See the `Graphics.FromImage()` documentation (also previously linked for this reason).

Comment: @Jimi - Okay, so I defined the new bitmap ````Bitmap final = new Bitmap(imgWidth, imgHeight);```` then I created the graphics object ````Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(final);```` and then I drew the images on the bitmap ````g.DrawImage(astroObject, new Point(0, 0));
     g.DrawImage(fovOutline, new Point(0, 0));```` and then I set the picture box to be the bitmap ````pictureBox.Image = final;```` when I run the code nothing happens (I run this in the Form Loader), where have I gone wrong?